# is it possible to modify BaseStyle of Manipulate dynamically?

Tags: manipulate

I can't decide what is a best color for the background for a Manipulate I am writing.

So, I thought since this is Manipulate, why not make this part configurable as well, so one can change the RGB color (using something like 3 sliders, one for each channel), so depending on the mood at that moment, one can choose different background color until they find one that they prefer.

But I am not sure how this can be done since `BaseStyle` is set when Manipulate itself is created. BaseStyle is an option and not a command.

Here is a small example of a Manipulate. I did not show the sliders for selecting the RGB color, since I do not know if it is even possible to modify the BaseStyle yet. This is just a toy Manipulate that just plots a sin function with greenish color for background of the Manipulate.

```
Manipulate[
 {},
 {m, 1, 10},

 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, -m, m}, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True,ImagePadding -> 30]]}}
  ],

 Paneled -> False,
 ContentSize -> {0},
 Frame -> False,
 Alignment -> Center,
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu",
 BaseStyle -> {Background -> RGBColor[.80, .80, .90]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The question is**: How to modify the Background color dynamically using an input from the user (via sliders, not shown). Is it possible? I just like to know the syntax if possible, and I can do the rest.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseStyle.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Background.html

I am using V9.

Please note that any solution can't use global variables. This is for a demo for WRI web site, and one of the rules is that no global variables are allowed (since they will interact with other copies of the Manipulate).

**update**

Using the official demonstration style sheet, when using `ContentSize -> {0}` and `Paneled -> False`, , Manipulate background is white by default. I thought that giving it little color might be nice. Here is an example

```
Manipulate[
 {},
 {m, 1, 10},

 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, -m, m}, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 30]]}}
  ],
 Paneled -> False,
 ContentSize -> {0},
 Alignment -> Center,
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might ask, well, this is because I set `Paneled->False` and this is true. But this was the only way to get rid of the small mark that remain there as result of doing `ContentSize -> {0}`. And there is no way to remove this mark. Here is an example

```
Manipulate[
 {},
 {m, 1, 10},

 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, -m, m}, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 30]]}}
  ],
 Paneled -> True,
 ContentSize -> {0},
 Alignment -> Center,
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That little square there at the corner, is impossible to get rid off. Only way is to do `Paneled->False`. That marker is a big problem, and here is a related question I asked about it before.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556234/how-to-not-show-the-scrollbars-when-contentsize-does-not-fit-the-content-in-mani

If I can figure a way to remove this tiny white spot, then I can leave `Paneled->True`. 
ps. I have to use `ContentSize -> {0}`. This is how I did the whole demo. Everything in the control area. No way to change this.

Looking now at the demo I have, this white spot is very small, may be no one will notice it. At least this way I do not have to change the 'official' background color. I will check on this and see. It is just annoying one can't get rid of it. Here is a screen shot, where I set `Paneled->True` again. I put small circle around it. If the demo editor says it is ok, then I am all set, do not need to change background color. Will ask.

**Update 12/23/12**

Ok, figured how remove last piece of code from the Manipulate expression and replaced it with `None`. So finally the white line marker is gone. Problem resolved. Using `None` was the trick that was needed thanks to  Michael E2.

Here it is (it is 2 panels, and one can select full screen or not using a checkbox).

One of the hardest things, is getting the sizes of the different plots correct and to fill the whole space in the grid. I spend half the time trying different values (aspect ratio, image sizes, padding, margins, etc.. for many things until I find the right combination. There got to be better way to do this but if there is, I do not know what it is). But this one is now finally done.

[image]

thanks,

Comment: To get rid of the white square, use `None` for the body instead of `{}` (line 2 of your code).  You can then omit `ContentSize->{0}` and `Paneled->True`.  Perhaps the same trick will work for the full demo.

Comment: It's a nicely packed, information-rich demo -- looks good.  I suppose an alternative would be to put the grid on the right into the content/body of the Manipulate, controls and all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the Background setting in Dynamic. The variables in the Background option seem to need to be global.  Either like this:

```
background = 1;
Manipulate[{}, {m, 1, 10}, 
 Grid[{{Dynamic[background = m; 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, -m, m}, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 30]]}}], Paneled -> False, ContentSize -> {0}, 
 Frame -> False, Alignment -> Center, 
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu", 
 BaseStyle -> {Background :> Dynamic@Hue[(background - 1)/9]}]
```

or perhaps like this:

```
Manipulate[{}, {m, 1, 
  10}, {{background, background = RGBColor[.80, .80, .90]}, 
  ColorSlider},
 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, -m, m}, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 30]]}}], Paneled -> False, ContentSize -> {0}, 
 Frame -> False, Alignment -> Center, 
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu", LocalizeVariables -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> {Background :> Dynamic@background}]
```

Comment: The `Background->` makes sense, given how Dynamic works.  The Demonstrations editors might want the background of Manipulate to be the standard one.  However if you want a nonstandard workaround, try `BaseStyle -> {Background -> Dynamic@background$$}` and `LocalizeVariables -> True`.  Keep the local variable named `background`.  The editors might not go for that, either.

Comment: The $$ is tagged onto the end of local variables.  So if you have a local variable `{var, ..}`, it will be store in the notebook as `var$$`.  The variable itself is created when the front end instantiates the dynamic module; the symbol create in the kernel will have a name of the form `var$$nnnn` where `nnnn` is a unique number.  Type ``?FE`*`` and you'll see your Manipulate variables.